# Cannot find "Gandi Standard SSL CA 2" certificate on my webserver, where is it?

Tags: ssl, webserver, certificates

I have installed a certificate on my webserver into `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

My certificate is signed by `Gandi Standard SSL CA 2` which is signed by `USERTrust RSA Certification Authority`.

The `USERTrust RSA Certification Authority` is stored on my webserver into `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` :

```
$ dpkg -S USERTrust_RSA
ca-certificates: /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt
```

But I cannot find the `Gandi Standard SSL CA 2` certificate, where is it stored ?